# ERROR: error fetching result: OCIStmtFetch2 failed to fetch next result row

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

Please help me on below error while running foreign table in Postgres.

```
ERROR: error fetching result: OCIStmtFetch2 failed to fetch next result row
DETAIL: ORA-03135: connection lost contact
Process ID: 172606
Session ID: 1010 Serial number: 24958
SQL state: HV00L
```

Comment: This is basically a question without content. Postgres version? Driver being used? Code being run? Define foreign table, accessing through FDW or Foreign Key relationship? Relevant Postgres log content?

Answer (score 0):

oracle_fdw caches Oracle database connections, and this error means that something dropped the connection. You should examine the Oracle and network setup if there is something misconfigured. Looking at the Oracle server log would also shed light on the matter.

Normally, if such an error occurs at the start of a transaction, oracle_fdw will automatically reconnect to Oracle.

For further diagnosis, I would need more context information.